# I want to add values to local storage on button click using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-local-storage, ng-storage

I want to add values to local storage on button click using angularjs . I use ngStorage module

**[Demo for plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/nkPeJu/)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, change function `cloneItem` to accept parameter like

```
$scope.cloneItem = function (todo) {
    $scope.$storage.notes.push({
        "age": todo.age, "id":todo.id
    });
}
```

Then in your view, pass in the related `todo` element

```
<td><button data-ng-click="cloneItem(todo)">insert id and age to localstorage</button></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

To skip duplicates a small check is needed

```
$scope.cloneItem = function (todo) {
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.$storage.notes.length - 1; i++) {
    if ($scope.$storage.notes[i].age !=todo.age && $scope.$storage.notes[i].id!=todo.id ) {
    $scope.$storage.notes.push({
        "age": todo.age, "id":todo.id
    });
   }
  }
}
```